# Confusion on the Old Google Data AP, new Google API, and the Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-data-api, google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-settings-api

Currently Google is migrating their [old Google Data API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/) to the new Google API.

When we do API queries over the old Google Data API, we usually use Zend Framework and the given consumer key/secret to do the authen/autho, which is fine.

Question is, is it possible to use the given consumer key/secret (from the Google Apps Marketplace listing) and the new [OAuth 2 Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2) to call the API? What I have been having is the error message `redirect_uri mismatched` issue and obviously Google Apps Marketplace provides no way to change this value. Even though they had provided a link for us to go to the API Console from the listing page, I cannot see the OAuth 2.0 options in my API Access page at all.

Did I missed out anything?

If let's say I need to use the [Google Apps Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-settings/), does it mean I need to separately create a new OAuth 2.0 API Access in the API Console, then, when I need to access user data, I need to do the Auth flow again using this new consumer key/secret/redirect? I can't set this permission in the Listing Manifest? (Not supported?)

Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Admin Settings is not yet migrated to the new google-api, AFAICS. Check out this list : http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs ;

you can however use the new google-api client libraries but you have to roll your own XML model for the given API, it is not so hard, [I did a similar thing for the Contact API](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-api-java-client/updated-min/google-api-java-client/kr8UHSQCw_0/ZecTnkEs2JMJ);

The consumer/key secret can be re-used normally if it is sufficiently scoped. A related project for your market app is automatically created in the Google Api console [from what I remember](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-apps-marketplace-api/api%2420console/google-apps-marketplace-api/l1BaiNPpGw8/8JRxBmxzJFkJ)..

Comment: Thanks for answering this as it has been unanswered for almost half a year! ;) We had, btw, did the usual OAuth when we need to request for new resources.